Is Sallatha Sutta's mental-physical paradigm confusing?
Sallatha Sutta says:
"Now, the well-instructed disciple of the noble ones, when touched with a feeling of pain, does not sorrow, grieve, or lament, does not beat his breast or become distraught. So he feels one pain: physical, but not mental.
But according to SN 41.6 With Kāmabhū (On the Cessation of Perception & Feeling):

Perceptions & feelings are mental;

Do you think the use of the physical-mental dichotomy is misleading for those familiar with SN41.6?  Or make us think about anything in particular?  It just seems like if you cross the two discourses the problem arises...

BE. Please do not delete your question again. Yesterday, I answered it but it disappeared. thanks

@user66697 what is nsp?

SN 41.6 refers to perception & feeling as the 'citta-sankhara', which means the conditioner of the mind (citta). What this means is perception & feeling can cause the mind (citta) to generate greed, hatred & delusion, as follows:

Bhikkhus, dependent on the eye and forms, eye-consciousness arises; the meeting of the three is contact; with contact as condition there arises a feeling felt as pleasant or painful or neither-painful-nor-pleasant.
When one is touched by a pleasant feeling, if one delights in it, welcomes it, and remains holding to it, then the underlying tendency to lust lies within one.
When one is touched by a painful feeling, if one sorrows, grieves and laments, weeps beating one’s breast and becomes distraught, then the underlying tendency to aversion lies within one.
When one is touched by a neither-painful-nor-pleasant feeling, if one does not understand as it actually is the origination, the disappearance, the gratification, the danger, and the escape in regard to that feeling, then the underlying tendency to ignorance lies within one.
MN 148

Importantly, SN 41.6 says:

Saññā ca vedanā ca cetasikā. Ete dhammā cittappaṭibaddhā
Perception and feeling are mental. They’re tied up with the
mind.

Note: the words cetasikā (ceto) and citta are synonymous.
SN 36.6 says:

They experience two feelings:
So dve vedanā vedayati—
physical and mental.
kāyikañca, cetasikañca.

In summary, SN 41.6 is only about mental (cetasika) feelings. It is not about physical (kāyika) feelings. The purpose of SN 41.6 is to explain how mental feeling & perception condition the citta (mind-heart). In other words, as explained in SN 36.6, physical (kāyika) feelings alone cannot condition (sankhara) the mind-heart (citta).
For more detail about physical & mental feelings, refer to SN 48.37.
